# Why does self closing tag work in a html document?

Tags: html, xhtml

I have a html document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
```

In it I have tags such as

```
<br />
```

But Im reading that this tag is an XHTML element. Yet it still works why?

Comment: `</br>` isn't a self closing tag - it's an end tag in XHTML and invalid in HTML. Did you mean `<br />`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers failed to implement parsers that correctly handled HTML 4 and earlier.

They should have treated `<br/>` as "A br element followed by a greater than sign", but instead implemented it as "A br element with a `/` attribute, what's a `/` attribute? We'll drop it". This led to the feature being marked as [something to avoid](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#h-B.3.3).

XHTML then exploited the bug for [HTML-Compatible XHTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#compatGuidelines).

HTML 5 then redefined it as syntactic sugar so the XHTML junkies could keep on using the syntax they were used to.

Comment: I've often wondered if the `/` really is treated like an attribute, then dropped. It seems to me like `/` is just treated as white space in the tag when looking for attribute names. Try this for example: http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/js/live-dom-viewer/?%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%0D%0A%3Cbody%3E%0D%0A%3Cbr%20%2Fa%2Fc%3D%22%22%20%3E

Comment: It doesn't really make any practical difference.

Comment: True, it just seems a little contrived to me.

Answer (score 5):

Original answer based on the question as written before a character was moved and completely changed it:

> But Im reading that `</br>` is an XHTML element.

It isn't. Is is the *end tag* for an element.

`<br />` would be a self closing tag (representing an entire element) in XHTML. In HTML 4 it means the same as `<br>&gt;` (although most browsers don't respect that) and in HTML 5 the `/` is meaningless syntactic sugar to keep people used to XHTML happy.

In XHTML `<br/>` means the same as `<br></br>` (the latter is an error in HTML documents).

> Yet it still works why?

Browsers perform enormous amounts of error correction to try to deal with the sort of bad markup that was prevalent in the late 90s.

They are not always consistent in how they recover from different errors (for example, I believe that some browsers will ignore that completely while others will treat it as a line break), so you should never depend on this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

It's the browser that get rid of these differences. Anyways the `</br>` with that slash is incorrect both in HTML and XHTML.

Occurring to http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp

```
 In HTML the <br> tag has no end tag.

 In XHTML the <br> tag must be properly
 closed, like this: <br />.
```

Comment: `</br>` is perfectly fine in XHTML, providing it is preceded by `<br>`. (This does not apply to HTML-compatible XHTML).

Comment: You're right, it may be compatible, but encouraging the use of a tag that starts with the "closing" syntax (using `</` ) doesn't seems a good thing to me, just this

Comment: Err. I think you misunderstand. The end tag syntax is only acceptable when writing an end tag, I never claimed otherwise.

Comment: Following his example, he seems to use `</br>` (ONLY) instead of `<br />` for the line breaks

Answer (score -1):

Self closing tag is valid format in XML

XHTML means all tag must be closed

```
HTML
<br> valid
<br/> valid
XHTML
<br> invalid
<br/> valid
```

Edited:

```
</br> is invalid anyway and you are lucky if browser fix it :)    
</br> is the same as <div id="gd"/>, both are invalid
```

Comment: Both `</br>` and `<div id="gd"/>` are valid in XHTML